# Creating numpy array at each point of a grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a vectorized way to create a 2D array at each point of a 2D grid, and have the result stored in a 4D array (or at least a way better than nested loops).

More specifically, I have a function which creates a matrix (2D array) given two numbers `H(x,y)`. I would like to use this function to create a matrix at each point of an `(x,y)` grid, and have the result be stored in a 4D array. Preferrably, if we have something like

```
x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

result = magic_function(xx, yy, H)
```

then the shape of `result` would be `(100,100,4,4)` (if `H` is making 4x4 matrices).

Comment: Is the function `H(x,y)` yours? That is, can you alter it?

Comment: `H(x,y)` - does that only accept scalar values?  Or will it work with arrays?  If it only accepts scalars, then it has to be called 100*100 times, once for each `x,y` pair.  `meshgrid` creates 2 `(100,100)` arrays.  A `vectorized` `H` would work directly with those 2 arrays.

Comment: @Ixop It's my function, so it can be modified however it needs to. @hpaulj I guess the question comes down to how to vectorize `H`. It's creating a 4x4 matrix. I know that I could take each `(100,100)` `meshgrid` array and make a new `(100,100)` array for each of the 16 entries in the matrix and then concatenate them together, but it seems to me like there should be a better way.